# Import Excel file into SQL Server - have issues on datatype

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have some Excel data got from SQL Server, but I updated the script of SQL Server, so I need to import Excel into SQL Server again. I used **task - import data**.

There are some errors:

> Copying to [dbo].[AA] (Error) Messages  . Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow
>   Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Invalid date format".  (SQL Server Import and Export
>   Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with
>   Destination - AA.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[Time] on
>   Destination - AA.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned
>   was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the
>   specified type.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination -
>   AA.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A
>   occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination -
>   AA.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error
>   occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There
>   may be error messages posted before this with more information about
>   the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on     component
>   "Destination - AA" (107) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
>   processing input "Destination Input" (120). The identified component
>   returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific
>   to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow
>   task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)

I don't know if anybody have any suggestions.

Because Excel file only have limited data type, i.e number is float type. There are a lot of datatypes are not matched with destination SQL Server table.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you include a sample of the data being imported, show what settings you used in the import wizard, and state what you have tried to resolve the individual errors. Have you identified which piece(s) of data is problematic? Maybe try importing a few rows and work on specific errors for those rows.

Answer (score 1):

For high performance and control data type conversion:

1) Save Excel to CSV text file using save As.

2) Use the following script to import data:

```
BULK
INSERT mytable
FROM 'path_to_csdv_file.csv'
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

You can use format file to describe data
for more details, review:

[BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data types are misaligned.  I thin the easiest thing to do is to use the Import Wizard to get the data types setup correctly.

http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s231/schedule_data_import_in_sql_server_pt2.htm

Once you have your data types setup correctly, do this:
right-click the table > Script Table As > Create To > New Query Editor Window.  Now, just copy/paste the results to Excel.  Fill in all data types for all fields.  Also, do this:

right-click the table > Script Table As > Insert To > New Query Editor Window.

Eventually, you should get something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Something]
 (
     [Date]    VARCHAR(MAX),
     Change    VARCHAR(MAX),
     Index_Code    VARCHAR(MAX),
     Price_Return_Level    VARCHAR(MAX)
)
  bulk insert dbo.GII_ICLstg
  from 'C:\your_path_to_file.txt'
  WITH
  (
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  )
  GO
  INSERT INTO dbo.Something
    SELECT
        [Date] = CASE WHEN ISDATE([Date])=1 THEN CAST([Date] AS DATETIME) ELSE NULL END,
        [Change],
        Index_Code,
        Price_Return_Level = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Price_Return_Level) = 1 
    FROM dbo.Something
```

Personally, I think that's the easiest way to do these kinds of things.